# junit not respecting maven classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

Environment:
Eclipse Juno 
Junit 4.11 
maven 3.0.4

Problem:

I believe i have a classloading problem when running a unit test in eclipse's junit runner.
My Specific problem stems from this code:

```
this.getClass().forName(type);
```

The above code will get called eventually with the name of a class that lives in an maven dependency (The dependency is simply a collection of java beans).
When i run a mvn test this code runs successfully, however if i use eclipse to run the junit tests i receive a class not found exception.

The classpath entry found in the classpath tab of the run configuration references the maven dependencies. So i'm not sure why the dependency isn't being pulled in.

Why would this be happening? I have the maven plugin installed in eclipse, so it should be using the same classpath.  Yet it seems that not everything is identical. I've tried doing cleans, updating maven project configuration and restarting eclipse.

.classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

.project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>brokenClasspathproject</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

junit config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launchconfig">
<stringAttribute key="bad_container_name" value="/brokenClasspathproject/junit"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/brokenClasspathproject"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
<listEntry value="4"/>
</listAttribute>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.CONTAINER" value="=brokenClasspathproject"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.KEEPRUNNING_ATTR" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.TESTNAME" value=""/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.TEST_KIND" value="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.loader.junit4"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_PROVIDER" value="org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value=""/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="brokenClasspathproject"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.SOURCE_PATH_PROVIDER" value="org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.sourcepathProvider"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

Comment: The test classpath is not included in the Eclipse project classpath by Maven. Otherwise you'd have all kinds of hell. Ensure that in your run target, you manually setup the classpath.

Comment: could you share your pom.xml content? Maybe you have the dependency just for testing

Comment: @EugenioCuevas I cannot, however it the dependency it is referencing does not have a scope defined.

Comment: @kabram This isn't true. When you run junit tests it adds the jars in the test scope. Otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: @ctwomey1 when you run the test from Eclipse, does the jar appear on the command line?

Comment: @MatthewFarwell What do you mean by that? when i run it from eclipse i'm using a saved configuration (i'll add it to original post)

It just occured to me that perhaps it's the m2e plugin that is breaking.

Comment: When you run it in eclipse, look at the process that is being run (JUnit runs as an external process), and see if your jar is on the command line.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell while the tests were running the classpath did have all the maven dependencies included.

A ps -ef shows:
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath **MAVEN ENTRIES** org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 47080 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -testNameFile /tmp/testNames2913360434860653613.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out why this is happening!

The code I was executing was simply:

```
this.getClass().forName(name);
```

Which was working in maven but not junit standalone.  However when i changed my property to be :

```
this.getClass().forName(com.packagename.name);
```

The code started to work. I'm assuming maven with surefire is doing some backend voodoo to recognize both name and com.packagename.name.  If I had actually stopped to read the javadocs I would have seen class.forName expects the package name.

So i guess the moral is to actually read the javadocs.  My apologies (and sincere gratitude!) to all that commented on this!